# Problem using XmlSerializer to Serialize/Deserialize a class between a Silverlight Library and an MVC App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, xml-serialization

Here is my situation:

I have a solution with three projects: 1) Silverlight App, 2) Silverlight Library, 3) the Asp.net-MVC Web App.

In the Silverlight Library I have a class called "MyClass".  In the Silverlight App I serialize that class to XML using XmlSerializer and send the XML back to the database.  I retrieve and deserialize that XML periodically in the Silverlight App to use MyClass.

My problem comes when I try to deserialize that XML from within the Asp.Net-MVC App.  Inside the Asp.Net-MVC App this is the code I use to deserialize the XML to MyClass:

```
 MySilverlightLibrary.MyClassObjects.MyClass newMyClass = null;

 Assembly ass = Assembly.Load("MySilverlightLibrary.MyClassObjects");
 Type ty = ass.GetType("MySilverlightLibrary.MyClassObjects.MyClass", true);

 XmlSerializer theSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ty);

 if( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlText) )
 {
    using( XmlReader sr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlText)) )
    {                 
       newMyClass = theSerializer.Deserialize(sr) as MySilverlightLibrary.MyClassObjects.MyClass;
    }
 }
```

This is the runtime error I get:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly '**System.Xml**, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I noticed that the version of the "System.Xml" reference in the Silverlight Library project is 2.0.5.0, but the "System.Xml" reference is 2.0.0.0 in the Asp.Net-MVC App.  I assume that this is likely the cause of the issue, but I can't figure out how to fix it!

I have been messing with this for quite some time now and it's driving me nuts!  As always, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - the cause of the problem you are having is the mismatched versions. 
I believe you can solve this with [Assembly binding redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(vs.71).aspx).